# Permissions problem with tlmgr

Tags: texlive, mac

I just updated tlmgr and installed a few fonts (type1cm, palimas, etc.).

However, when I attempt to use them, I get a "permission denied" error.  Which makes sense when I look at the permissions of the folder they are installed in:

```
drwx------    3 root  wheel   102 Jul 24 14:02 type1cm
```

However, all other packages in the texlive folder are the right permissions:

```
drwxr-xr-x   14 root  wheel   476 May 24 08:38 amsfonts
```

I'm not sure what caused tlmgr to install things with the wrong permissions, and would like to make sure it doesn't happen again.

Any ideas?

I'm on OS X 10.10 using MacTex 2015 Basic.  The above folders are in:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex
```

Comment: How did you install them exactly? What command did you run? If you said `sudo tlmgr...`, what does `sudo umask` give? If you ran as root (doubtful on OS X), what does `umask` give as root?

Comment: Sudo umask gives 0077.

Comment: That isn't the problem, then. That's plenty permissive enough.

Comment: Your umask is too restrictive; system default is 0022. FYI, if you ran TeX Live Utility, it would warn you of this.